# How to add contact form instead of checkout

Tags: forms, contact

I want to delete the checkout and add a form instead. So instead of checkout it will be a form which can send an email with information from the form (Contact + Items from the cart). Exactly like [this](http://www.lovekushfoods.in/firmhardware/en_US/order-form/)

My actual page is [this](http://firmhardware.com/cart/) - you can add a product / item in the cart to see.

Answer (score 0):

## Checkout Deletion

I guess you are using Woocommerce even though you did not mention it.

I didn't understand why you want to delete the checkout page, but to do so, just go to Pages under the WordPress admin dashboard, and delete the checkout page.

## Contact Form Installation

1. To add a contact form to your WordPress site, just install the [Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) plugin,
   and generate a new form.
   You will have a generated Shortcodeon the top of the form creation page,
   copy it for later.
2. Create new page: Pages -> new page
3. Add the generated Shortcode to the page content.
4. publish.

Comment: I use woocommerce, but I want to receive emails from the form which the client set in the cart. To receive information like name of the product, quantity of products. Some sort of inquiry. Thank you.